# What is the "AdMob Offline Notifications" notification channel?

Tags: android, admob, notification-channel

All of the sudden I saw that our app had a new notification channel named *"AdMob Offline Notifications"*.

We do use AdMob, so I assume it's created by Google's library, but I can't find any documentation on it. I'm wondering on what that channel is used for, and if it's possible to not have it at all.

The channel is created as soon as the app is started the first time. The id of it is `offline_notification_channel` and its importance is set to low (no vibration, no sound).

I did manage to find others wondering about the same at https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/search?q=%22admob%20offline%20notifications%22 , but no answers so far.

Comment: The Admob team acknowledged that its a bug on their end, hopefully they will be able to patch this up ASAP - https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/QWpl3IiGhho/m/v-b3QvrIAgAJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until [Admob fixes this issue](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/QWpl3IiGhho/m/v-b3QvrIAgAJ) as [Oush pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64694428/what-is-the-admob-offline-notifications-notification-channel#comment114659050_64694428), you can just delete the notification channel right after it was crated by admob, so it won't confuse your users:

```kotlin
MobileAds.initialize(context) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel("offline_notification_channel")
  }
}
```